# Order of continuity of product of two smooth functions

Tags: functions, continuity, taylor-expansion

I have an integral over an open and bounded domain, $\Omega$, of the form
$$\int_{\Omega}\cal{U}\cal{V}{\rm d}\Omega $$
where $\cal{U}\in \cal{C}^{r}$ and $\cal{V}\in\cal{C}^{s}$ and $r \le s$, let's say the derivatives $\cal{U}^{(r+1)}$ and $\cal{V}^{(s+1)}$ exist.

If the product $\cal{UV}\in \cal{C}^q$, is it always true that $q=r+s$?

Comment: In general, $uv$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\min\{r,s\}}$i.e $q\geq \min\{r,s\}$. For example, if $f$ is $C^r$ but not $C^{r+1}$, then think about how absurd it would be if you consider the product $f\cdot 1 = f$ (the constant function $1$ is clearly $C^{\infty}$) and this turned out to be $C^{r+\infty} = C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Thanks!! didn't see it that way!

Comment: This is just an application of the product rule (and induction if you want to make it a super formal proof), because by the formula $(fg)' = f'g + fg'$, we see that if $f$ and $g$ are $C^{k+1}$, then each function on the RHS, $f,f',g,g'$ is atleast $C^k$, so by the induction hypothesis, $(fg)'$ will be $C^k$, and hence $fg$ is $C^{k+1}$. Basically, you can only differentiate as few times as your worst behaved function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool question. If you have $\mathcal{U} \times \mathcal{V}$ and $\mathcal{U}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{r+1}$, $\mathcal{V}$ is $\mathcal{C}^{s+1}$ then the product will be in $\mathcal{C}^q$ where $q=min\{r,s\}$.

Think of a product of two functions as a restriction of some kind: you're only allowed to differentiate the product as many times as allowed by the differentiability of the function with the most restrictions on it. How many times you can differentiate is controlled by the function which has the most restriction imposed on it basically.

Hope that made sense